# HTTP 503 Error: Programmatically trying to fetch data from Hashicorp's Vault (v1.5.5)

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to programmatically fetch data from Hashi Vault (v1.5.5), but keep getting a HTTP 503 error, no matter how I've tried to send the Vault API request (via spring boot webclient, via spring.vault template).  When I check the status of vault, it is initialize and unsealed.  In the Vault UI, I can view the data that I want to access.  When I use curl (see below), I can fetch the data.  When I use the cli for vault, I can fetch the data.

From all of the examples that I've seen, this is easy, but I am wondering whether I am missing something programmatically... An assumption... Like, my code has to issue its own request to unseal the Vault???  To eliminate auth/permission issues, I am using the root token.  I'd really appreciate any suggestions or ideas, because I have run out of them!
Thank you for your time and interest in my issue.

```
vault status
Key             Value
---             -----
Seal Type       shamir
Initialized     true
Sealed          false
Total Shares    1
Threshold       1
Version         1.5.5
Cluster Name    vault-cluster-435e5f26
Cluster ID      c1b269b8-4a9a-5e9c-e468-85e2e55eb261
HA Enabled      true
HA Cluster      https://192.168.0.3:8201
HA Mode         active
```

```
vault kv list csc/tenants
Keys
----
dev:111122223333444422221111
abc:111111111159999999999999
def:1234asdf1234asdf1324asdf
```

```
curl --location \
-H "X-Vault-Request:true" \
-H "X-Vault-Token:${VAULT_TOKEN}" \
--request GET "${VAULT_ADDR}/v1/csc/metadata/tenants?list=true" | jq
{
  "request_id": "ba228321-5b99-40f1-69f2-5b8122bc47df",
  "lease_id": "",
  "renewable": false,
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "data": {
    "keys": [
      "dev:111122223333444422221111",
      "abc:111111111159999999999999",
      "def:1234asdf1234asdf1324asdf"
    ]
  },
  "wrap_info": null,
  "warnings": null,
  "auth": null
}
```

```
// Here is the webflux.fn code that returns 503...
val wc = WebClient
  .builder()
  .baseUrl("http://localhost:8200")
  .defaultHeaders { httpHeaders: HttpHeaders ->
      httpHeaders.set("X-Vault-Request", "true")
      httpHeaders.set("X-Vault-Token", "s.888888888855111111111111")
      HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE
      MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
  }.build()

val res = wc
  .get()
  .uri("/v1/csc/metadata/tenants?list=true")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToFlux(VaultKvSecretResponse::class.java)
  .map {
      println(it.data.keys.first())
  }
  .subscribe()
```

```
// Here is the Spring Vault code that returns 503...
@Configuration
class AppConfig2 : AbstractVaultConfiguration() {
  override fun vaultEndpoint(): VaultEndpoint = VaultEndpoint.from(URI(environment.getRequiredProperty("VAULT_ADDR"))
  override fun clientAuthentication(): ClientAuthentication = TokenAuthentication(environment.getRequiredProperty("VAULT_TOKEN"))
}

@SpringBootApplication
class SbcloudApplication(
  private val environment: Environment,
  private val vaultTemplate: VaultTemplate
) : CommandLineRunner {
    val result = vaultTemplate.list("http://localhost:8200/v1/csc/metadata/data/tenants")
}
```

Comment: Is `http://localhost:8200` the same as `VAULT_ADDR`?

Comment: Yes, what is so odd is that the same uri works when using the vault cli and curl...  I know that the v2 key-value engine requires inserting 'data', but I wonder if it is the problem...

Comment: I repeated my experiment using com.bettercloud.vault.Vault, which automatically accounts for 'data' when using a v2 kv engine, and had the same results.  I am going t switch to a different computer and see what happens...

Comment: and where are your logs and the exception?